# Decrypting Android RSA: Invalid Ciphertext Exception

Tags: java, android, encryption, cryptography

I am creating a cross platform Android/Windows app.

I use this code to generate a public key in Android I can use from the test public key that was generated from the Windows app:

```
         String AppKeyPub = "MIGHAoGBAONcDWYnbGGOIG1wfHy8v54/2Ch2ZCewcM6TGGtnvHOa/53ekPlCYHXG5UDeaCUxPwPK" +
"Fx9qikj04nxF+tKl9GnV4RS+3kDQPkunlJ4pk52PiKVGaVpOWOli1Y31zJJZ9ufqLySEycJVuqiI" +
"Z9kektzkHdAIxNKlPDn4GQa2mjz/AgER"; 

            try {
                // PREP PUBLIC KEY
                byte[] decoded = Base64.decode(AppKeyPub,0);
                org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey pkcs1PublicKey = org.bouncycastle.asn1.pkcs.RSAPublicKey.getInstance(decoded);
                BigInteger modulus = pkcs1PublicKey.getModulus();
                BigInteger publicExponent = pkcs1PublicKey.getPublicExponent();
                RSAPublicKeySpec keySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(modulus, publicExponent);
                KeyFactory kf = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
                PublicKey publicKey = kf.generatePublic(keySpec);
```

I use this code then to encrypt a test message:

```
byte[] input = "Hello from Android!".getBytes("UTF-8");
        Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA", "BC");
        cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);                

        byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
        int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
        ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
        String encodedData = Base64.encodeToString(cipherText, messageCount);
        System.out.println(new String(encodedData));
        System.out.println(ctLength);
```

This is the encrypted test message generated by Android:

> fy1l1g/Tpxer4mR3bO6WQdfmi93I/YjpZZDGvIiZ6UU/VZWhnmgmuU1zM6EqwppqQTMkfsKPk5kAWhSYH8+tbyvgh/Cd48rTKJ39MCfnwCNZvSvNKETZbhgy5fVGL/Uisn16AOae0DI4gV4kubrGswhEFUpyp8seAPclKgHbGuQ=

The problem is when I try to decrypt the message in the Windows app it fails with the error message:

> RSA/OAEP-MGF1(SHA-1):invalid ciphertext

I've tried different combinations of Android BC algorithms and they all give me the same result. I've also tried no_wrap no_padding etc. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks for any advice at all.

Comment: Is the Windows application doing a Base64 Decode before decrypting?

Comment: No you weren't. You provided one end of a two-ended problem. The presumption that you didn't encrypt it correctly is overwhelming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have OAEP padding in the Windows app. At least in later versions, OAEP padding is the default. I'll just show you how to perform OAEP padding as it is - possibly after the less known KEM scheme - probably the most secure one for RSA:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("RSA/NONE/OAEPPADDING", "BC");
cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, publicKey);                
byte[] cipherText = new byte[cipher.getOutputSize(input.length)];
int ctLength = cipher.update(input, 0, input.length, cipherText, 0);
ctLength += cipher.doFinal(cipherText, ctLength);
```

Comment: THAT WORKED! Maarten you are a lifesaver. I was using provider.getServices(); but I never saw "RSA/NONE/OAEPPADDING" in the list as an option? I would upvote your answer but I can't now thanks to the downvote on this question for no reason.

Comment: There is RSA//OAEPPADDING , which needs some kind of compatible mode in between the slashes. NONE is probably the best one, but ECB is also possible (for compatibility with Oracle's providers, but IMHO incorrect).

Comment: Thanks again Maarten. I've upvoted your answer. Now to get the encryption working in the other direction...